# IFTTT is triggering my "Blogger to WordPress" recipe twice

Tags: blogger, wordpress, if-this-then-that

I have connected my Blogger blog to WordPress for auto post through IFTTT. But for the last week IFTTT is triggering the recipe two or three times, causing duplicate posts on my WordPress blog. How can I fix it so the recipe only runs once?

My recipe detail is like this:

```
If any new post on your Blogger blog, then create a post on your WordPress blog
```

and I am receiving error messages like this:

> WordPress
>   WordPress Action Error about 4 hours ago
>   An error with WordPress prevented your Recipe from working. Edit the WordPress Channel or try again. If errors persist, visit the Help page for support.

Comment: It would probably be useful to see the recipe. What's your input? A feed? (Please [edit] your question.)

Comment: Sounds like a transient error at IFTTT. You should probably contact them directly. (In my experience, IFTTT support is usually pretty responsive.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a feedback loop has started. My guess is that your Blogger is triggering your WordPress and your WordPress is triggering your Blogger.   I would try looking into the settings of this Applet (used to be called recipe).

- First:  Try to alter the settings of the running/ active Applet that could fix this problem.
- Second:  Maybe you have two Applets (recipes) running.  One that is 'pushing' your Blogger to WordPress, and One that is 'pushing' your WordPress posts to Blogger
- Final option:  Delete your Applet and manually recreate it.

(Side note: I had an issue recently where a feedback loop started between my FB and Twitter account, causing a tweet to be republished several times as a FB story pushed through as a tweet and again and again. Simply it was a digital feedback loop expressed through my social media accounts.  Most surprisingly, I did not alter anything before it started.  It had been running smoothly for months and then suddenly the loop started.  I solved my issue by deleting the Applet - Option 3)